# opensolaris alarm, what is it from?

Tags: opensolaris

I just created an opensolaris nas box last week, and this afternoon a loud alarm started going off.  What is that and how do I turn it off?

-- update --

The alarm appears to be coming form the mother board (intel).

I moved the box away from the wall so the back of it could vent better and a minute later the alarm went off.  I'm wondering if the alarm had something to do with temperature.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like a temperature alarm. Have you tried looking at the documentation for the motherboard? Also, are you able to check the BIOS to see whether there are settings for temperature alarms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you have already gathered, I am inclined to agree with you. If the box is close enough to the wall that it prevented air from being directed out of the back, you would be getting temperature related issues/alarms.

Comment: any way I can tell what's going on from the CLI?

Comment: I would recommend looking into the documentation for your motherboard as this sounds like it is the one responsible for the alarm and not opensolaris.

Comment: Yep it's the CPU overheating, it's the same issue as posted here:

http://www.techsupportforum.com/hardware-support/motherboards-bios-cpu/174520-solved-pc-beeping-please-help.html